# How to import framework into XCode project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, object

I get `No such module 'BRLMPrinterKit'` error.

I take a reference from official document https://support.brother.com/g/s/es/htmldoc/mobilesdk/guide/getting-started/getting-started-ios.html to import framework.

Here is my step:

1. drag `BRLMPrinterKit.framework` and `BRLMPrinterKitW.framework` into my framework folder
   [image]
2. Check they are in Link Binary With Libraries (remove and drag again)
   [image]
3. Check Framework Search Paths (I'm not sure it correct or not)
   [image]
4. Check Header Search Paths (I'm not sure it correct or not)
   [image]

Finally I clean and build get `No such module 'BRLMPrinterKit'` error.

I have no idea how to fix my import problem, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: the mentioned guide seems to imply that you only need one of the two frameworks, did you tried to integrate only one of those?

Comment: I try your suggestion just drag `BRLMPrinterKit.framework`, it still shows the error :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a Swift module, so first, you need to create a bridging header, in which you import <BRLMPrinterKit/BRLMPrinterKit.h>, then you can use the BRLM classes in your Swift files.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, I noticed it is not Swift module, I change the code to bridging header, fix the import error now. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try using CocoaPods to install the framework, it's more convenient and faster.
Your framework supports installation using cocoapods

https://cocoapods.org/

https://github.com/jonathantribouharet/BRLMPrinterKit

Comment: This is a good suggestion but not an answer to question he is asking.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I still try the CocoaPods. I thought it should work, but still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

1. using CocoaPods to install the 'BRLMPrinterKit' framework.
2. add the bridge file.(Targets > Build Settings > Swift Compiler - General > Objective-C Bridgeing Header)
   [image]

the bridge file.h

```html
#ifndef PtouchPrinterKit_Bridging_Header_h
#define PtouchPrinterKit_Bridging_Header_h

#import <BRLMPrinterKit/BRPtouchBluetoothManager.h>
#import <BRLMPrinterKit/BRPtouchDeviceInfo.h>
#import <BRLMPrinterKit/BRPtouchNetworkManager.h>
#import <BRLMPrinterKit/BRPtouchPrinter.h>
#import <BRLMPrinterKit/BRPtouchPrinterData.h>
#import <BRLMPrinterKit/BRPtouchPrinterKit.h>
#import <BRLMPrinterKit/BRPtouchPrintInfo.h>

#endif
```

3. then you can use the framework

Comment: I have followed these steps and it has gotten rid of the no framework error but now I get the error "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code" when I go to build the project. It's definitely caused by the Pod because when I remove it everything works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: I changed the pod to v4.0.1 and now everything works fine. I'm gonna guess my cocoa pods or something isn't up to date enough for the newest version. Thanks!