# can't load brother SDK to capacitor custom plug in

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I have been searching all over and I have not found any good documentation in how can I create a custom ionic capacitor plug-in with an external SDK (Brother printer SDK).  This SDK is located locally in my computer.

The Error I keep getting is the following.

```
No such module 'BRLMPrinterKit'
```

I'm building the plug in with

```
npm init @capacitor/plugin@latest
```

I follow the steps found in
[How to embed third party framework on ionic capacitor custom plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58045726/how-to-embed-third-party-framework-on-ionic-capacitor-custom-plugin)

I was expecting to use the Brother printer SDK in the custom capacitor plug in. Any tip in how can I implement a custom plug in with any framework?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know very well about ios plugins for ionic, but I recommend you to use this post to create the plugin step by step (I used it for android plugins):
https://devdactic.com/build-capacitor-plugin

I think you can use this other post to solve that specific issue: [How to import framework into XCode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63720776/10500723)

I know it's not the best answer, but I hope it helps.